# Resize SWT table with editors

Tags: java, swt

I am using a SWT table with editors (Text, Combo and Check) in the Cells and I want to resize the columns correctly to the text. I tried the TableColumn's Pack method but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the sample that I use

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell( display );
    shell.setLayout( new FillLayout() );
    Table table = new Table( shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI );
    table.setLinesVisible( true );
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        TableColumn column = new TableColumn( table, SWT.NONE );
        column.setWidth( 100 );
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < 12; i++ )
    {
        new TableItem( table, SWT.NONE );
    }
    TableItem[] items = table.getItems();
    for ( int i = 0; i < items.length; i++ )
    {
        TableEditor editor = new TableEditor( table );
        CCombo combo = new CCombo( table, SWT.NONE );
        combo.setText( "CCombo" );
        combo.add( "item  1" );
        combo.add( "A very lengthyyyyyyyyy item 2" );
        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.setEditor( combo, items[i], 0 );
        editor = new TableEditor( table );
        Text text = new Text( table, SWT.NONE );
        text.setText( "A very lengthyyyyyyyy  text" );
        editor.grabHorizontal = true;
        editor.setEditor( text, items[i], 1 );
        editor = new TableEditor( table );
        final Button button = new Button( table, SWT.CHECK );
        button.pack();
        editor.minimumWidth = button.getSize().x;
        editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;
        editor.setEditor( button, items[i], 2 );
    }
    //resize columns
    for ( TableColumn columm : table.getColumns() )
        columm.pack();

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while ( !shell.isDisposed() )
    {
        if ( !display.readAndDispatch() )
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: YOu should use TableViewer and editing support

Answer (score -2):

do something like this :
first

```
 table.setRedraw(false) ;
```

and do your job
at the end set it true , like this :

```
 table.setRedraw(true);
```

Comment: @omidhaghighatgoo If you are sure that this will work, then please explain where *exactly* you would use these two commands. Ideally post a complete working example...